# Como podría hacer que en una consulta un SUM() se repita

Tags: mysql, sql

Amigos Como podría hacer que en una consulta un SUM() se repita,sin hacer una subconsulta, por ejemplo esta consulta:

```
SELECT boletoserie, boletonumero, monto, sum(monto) FROM boletos_bol
```

y me muestre mas o menos estos datos, la suma que se repita al final:

FV32    123   20    90 
FV32    124   30    90 
FV32    125   40    90

Comment: La suma que dices es la suma de todos los registros? ese 90 es la suma de todos los registros de esa tabla?

Comment: Juan, por favor **[edit] la pregunta** explicando mejor tu problema. Agrega las tablas y ejemplos de datos que contienen las tablas que deseas usar. Lee [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Algo como esto podria funcionarte

```
SELECT boletoserie, boletonumero, monto, 
@suma:=IF(@suma IS NULL,0,@suma)+sum(monto) 
FROM boletos_bol
```

@suma - Es la variable que va almacenando el monto

Uso el IF porque en la primera pasada @suma es nulo

```
<?
//ME CONECTO AL SERVER
$link=new PDO('mysql:host=SERVIDOR;dbname=BASE','USUARIO','´PASS');
//EJECUTO LA SQL
$result=$link->query("SELECT boletoserie, boletonumero, monto, 
@suma:=IF(@suma IS NULL,0,@suma)+sum(monto) 
FROM boletos_bol");
//RECORRO LA RESPUESTA
foreach($result as $row){
    var_dump($row); //IMPRIMO RESULTADO
}
?>
```

Anexo un ejemplo de una conexión PDO en PHP con el que hice la prueba

Saludos :)

Comment: amigo Ruben Hernandez, pero eso seria con un procedimiento almacenado?, no me funciona asi, me pide un valor

Comment: Ahora esta Listo :)

Answer (score 0):

En SQL puedes utilizar SUM(tucolumna)OVER()... te hara la sumatoria como la necesitas, en tu caso seria de la siguiente forma.

```
SELECT boletoserie, boletonumero, monto, sum(monto)over() FROM boletos_bol
```

Saludos, espero te funcione.

Comment: para que sirve el uso de over() ?

Comment: Que tal Alfredo.... en este caso la clausula OVER() trabaja sobre la consulta final obtenida, y hace la sumatoria de todos los registros y la muestra para cada uno de ello.. puedes encontrar mas documentacion en la siguiente url: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017........... saludos.

Comment: entiendo, sin embargo el enlace es para sql server y el OP de acuerdo a etiquetas usa mysql